# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter обработчик событий

Tags: java, android

Использую SimpleCursorTreeAdapter для того что бы отобразить дерево:

- категории

  - подкатегории

    - товары

На картинке  показаны только группы и под группы.
Метод
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {}
выполняется при нажатии на категорию, меня интересует можно ли как то обработать нажатие на 'под категорию' так что бы потом каким то образом отобразить еще список товаров можно в этом же дереве либо уже в другом активити,  или каким то другом способом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends Activity {
ExpandableListView elvMain;
DatabaseHandler db;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_market);


    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Cursor categoryData = db.getCategoryData();

    startManagingCursor(categoryData);

    String[] groupFrom = { DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_NAME };
    int[] groupTo = { android.R.id.text1 };

    String[] childFrom = { DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_NAME };
    int[] childTo = { android.R.id.text1  };

    // create adapter and a custom list
    SimpleCursorTreeAdapter sctAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, categoryData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
            groupTo, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, childFrom,
            childTo);

    elvMain = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvMain);

    elvMain.setAdapter(sctAdapter);

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
}

class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(AllProductsActivity context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout,
                     String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout,
                     String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
    }

    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        // gettting cursot by elements for concrete group
        int idColumn = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_ID);
        return db.getSubCategoryData(groupCursor.getInt(idColumn));
    }
}
```

}

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


some code...


//get category where idParent = 1
public Cursor getCategoryData() {
    return this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_CATEGORY, null, COLUMN_ID_PARENT + " = "
            + 1, null, null, null, null);
}

//get subCategory where idParent = category.id
public Cursor getSubCategoryData(long categoryID) {
    return this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_CATEGORY, null, COLUMN_ID_PARENT + " = "
            + categoryID, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. С помощью этого метода `setOnChildClickListener` который есть в `ExpandableListView`

В **MyAdapter** добавить метод

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
   super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

   String someData = cursor.getString(COLUMN_INDEX_WITH_DATA_URI);
   view.setTag("value", someData);

 }
```

далее в обработчике **setOnChildClickListener** из параметра view, вытащить необходимые данные с помощью `view.getTag("value");`

Если необходимо построить дерево с большей вложенностью, можно посмотреть на эту бибилиотеку  https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

Comment: т.е. стандартных способов типа .setOnClickListener нету? Эту проблему можно решить только библиотекой?

Comment: setOnChildClickListener  в ExpandableListView дает мне только номер позиции, но не дает курсор с данными об объекте который был выбран, как в случае  protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor).  Мне нужно знать что за объект был выбран, потому что на основании этого будет определяться дальнейшая логика работы приложения.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, а что если попробовать переопределить bindChildView в SimpleCursorTreeAdapter и в View добавлять необходимую информацию(если ее немного, допустим айдишник или что там еще нужно) с помощью метода setTag(), а уже в setOnChildClickListener просто брать из View эти данные с помощью метода getTag()

Comment: @EugeneKuzmenko Подходит, мне достаточно знать название или id категории которая была выбрана,  а можно пример, как это реализовать  в моем коде?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, обновил ответ

Comment: @EugeneKuzmenko Работает. Спасибо!)

Comment: @KirillStoianov Всегда пожалуйста)